# Is there an HTML5 alert box?

Tags: html

I am using HTML5 on an iPad application.

Is there anything like an alert box that I can use to show a message? I know HTML5 has a dialog box but if there is an alert box that would be better.

Comment: What is wrong with alert("woo"); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the good old-fashioned JavaScript alerts:

```
alert("Hey!  Pay attention!")
```

See here:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp